# Meaning of "extenuate": "extenuated the difficulties"

Tags: meaning-in-context

The definition of [**extenuate** as a verb](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/extenuate) is:

> to cause a wrong act to be judged less seriously by giving reasons for it:

Yet I don't apprehend its meaning herein. Would someone please explain? What's the "wrong act"?

> Less than four years after the demise of the 1898 reform movement,
>   Liang published an editorial in his journal, Hsin-min ts’r"mg-pao (The
>   New People Magazine), which argued vigorously for the necessity
>   of p’o-huai, or destruction.“ Sick of double-talk, he declared that any
>   scholar of resolve (chih-shih) must absolutely refuse to condone the
>   corruptions of the time—corruptions which would soon destroy the
>   entire system. Moreover, those who refused to recognize that “destruc-
>   tion in the end cannot be avoided” simply **extenuated** the diﬂiculties of
>   the present, for history proved that human progress was impossible with-
>   out destruction. England could not have reached her current great
>   power status without the civil war of the seventeenth century, which
>   cleared away feudal debris; the United States of America owed its

Source: P150 at http://books.google.com/books?id=ORMNHQGDuBgC&pg=PA150&dq=%22extenuated+the%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=pVabU_KNN83fkgX5i4DQCQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22extenuated%20the%22&f=false

Comment: As OED points out in their definition 7b - ***Improperly used for:** To extenuate the guilt of; to plead partial excuses for.* The definition you want here (where it's "properly" used) is simply [*to lessen or attempt to lessen the magnitude or seriousness of*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/extenuate), so I figure this is General Reference.

Comment: Yes. 'The definition of XXX is YYYYYY' is usually followed by **one** of the definitions given in the first dictionary that came to hand. Collins has: **emaciate (v)** 4.
a. to emaciate or weaken
b. to dilute or thin out >> So 'stretched out' / extended seems to be one possible reading. Collins doesn't flag this usage, but I'll point out that AHD does, as 'archaic'. I can't tell from OP, but this may be a quote from 1898, when it probably wasn't 'archaic'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such a use of *extenuate* is not grammatical anywhere, nor does it make any sense in your context. The author clearly means 'these people made the difficulties worse', and I would guess the word intended was *exacerbate*; where the mistake arose I cannot say.